# key vs. hash in a std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, containers

I often need a container where an hash is associated to an arbitrary object (collisions are theoretically possible if two different objects have the same hash).

In C++98 I would use `template<class Key, class T> class std::map` using `Key` as the hash computed on `T`:

```
struct object;
typedef std::string object_hash;

object_hash compute_hash(const object& obj);

std::map<object_hash, object> hash_map;

object_hash insert_or_assign(const object& obj)
{
    object_hash hash = compute_hash(obj);
    hash_map[hash] = obj;
    return hash;
}

std::pair<bool, object> get_at(const object_hash& hash)
{
    std::map<object_hash, object>::iterator iter = hash_map.find(hash);
    if( iter == hash_map.end() )
        return std::pair<bool, object>(false, object());
    else
        return std::pair<bool, object>(true, iter->second);
}
```

But starting from C++11 we have hashed containers so I expected something like:

```
template<class T, class Key = std::hash<T>> class std::hashed_map
```

with the requirement to provide a custom `std::hash` for type `T`, but instead we have

```
template<class Key, class T, class Hash = std::hash<Key>> class unordered_map
```

which does not apply to my scenario where the key is the hash itself, and there is no other "key" concept related to the arbitrary object.

Similar to what I expected is:

```
template<class Key, class Hash = std::hash<Key>> class unordered_set
```

but there are no lookup functions based on hash.

In modern C++ is there a built in container that uses hashes and has a lookup interfaces based on these hashes?

Comment: I think you need to have a look on wikipedia as to what hash maps are. What you did in C++03 is wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Any hashed container needs a real key to disambiguate hash collisions, because hashes are (in general) lossy. So, the situation where you need both a real key and a hash, is precisely the normal use-case where the hash is for quick lookups that may produce collisions. Why do you want to generate the hash yourself instead of letting the container invoke what is presumably the same hasher for you?

Comment: So maybe I'm misusing the term "hash map", but the need here is very clear: associate an arbitrary object with a hash. There is no additional "key" for that object. It's something like git, where each commit has its hash, and yes, theoretically collisions are possible.

Comment: Well, ignoring the possibility of collisions may be stupid under certain circumstances or acceptable in others. However, C++ containers just don't work like that, they provide 100% reliability even in the case of hash collisions. Why make compromises?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the point is that I don't have any other key in this scenario besides the hash. Git uses SHA-1 and ignores collisions as they are statistically unlikely (unless a deliberate collisions attack).

Comment: In scenarios where the key is equal to the value, the right container is a `set<>`. The comparator is then defined so that it only compares the hash. Of course, this doesn't really adress collisions. If you wanted that, I think there's an `unordered_set<>`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I have a value and its hash; i don't have any additional key. The unordered_set is not suitable as I can't access a stored item by its hash. The unordered_map is redundant because both the key and the hash are equals. But it is clear from other answers that the standard library don't have the container that I need.

Comment: Actually, it does: `std::map`. The problem with your question is the confusion caused by the use of the term "hash". What you have is an identifier (or, at least it's used like one because hash collisions are ignored). The fact that this ID is created by hashing the commit content is completely irrelevant, it remains a simple key/value mapping. In particular, it doesn't mean that you want or need any container that does any hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally the `unordered_map` was called `hash_map`, then the ISO C++ committee wisely renamed it, because the important difference between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is **not** that the first uses binary trees while the latter uses hashes, **but** that the first is ordered while the latter guarantees constant-time complexity.

So the fact that `std::unordered_map` uses hashes internally is little more than an implementation detail: you only need to provide an `std::hash` specialization if *the key* is a custom type (and the key is unfrequently a custom type). Apart from that, you should forget about the internal hashes of this container.

Despite some comments, if your key is the hash then there’s absolutely nothing wrong with you C++98 implementation. You can keep using it in C++ >= 11, updating and tiding it to the new language facilities where possible.

Comment: Another consideration was to avoid using names like `hash_map` which were already in use by some compiler vendors  (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have a map not a hash map; the fact your key is a hash is irrelevant to the container.

About the only salient feature is that you rarely care about the order of hashes; so unordered map is probably best.

Take your old solution, replace map with unordered map, replace `less` operstion with `equal` and a  hash (possibly down) to 64 bits.  For example, the classic pointer hash is just `reinterpret_cast<unit_ptr>( key )`.